# OS X run system application with GUI over all others including fullscreen apps

Tags: macos, mouse, fullscreen

I'm trying to write an accessibility app based on a "no-click" mouse concept. The idea is to capture mouse gestures that will be interpreted as clicks and pass the events to other apps. I have most of it working, except that I don't know how I could run it on top of fullscreen apps post Lion. Right now the app window is transparent and follows the mouse around, but this approach won't work with other "Desktops" or full screen apps, as the app stays in its current desktop when switching.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed was to call

```
[self setCollectionBehavior: NSWindowCollectionBehaviorCanJoinAllSpaces | NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenAuxiliary];
```

and also (important for the fullscreen apps!) set `Application is agent (UIElement)` to true in the info.plist file.

Comment: Thank you! Been looking for ages for this. So simple!